# django-easy-select2 Select2Multiple widget doesn't render

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2

The [installation page](http://django-easy-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) looked simple enough. I installed it, added `easy_select2` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings, ran `collectstatic`, and then had this in my form:

```
from easy_select2 import Select2Multiple
# from django_select2 import forms as select2_forms

class LeadForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    overseas_company = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=countries,
        label='Do you have any companies overseas and where?',
        widget=Select2Multiple()
    )
```

But it still renders as if I had done nothing at all. I tried `django_select2` as well, and it didn't work either, so I must be doing something wrong Select2 wise.

I tried looking at the HTTP request log. Merely enabling `easy_select2` doesn't make the template request the jQuery/select2 js files that are needed for the Select2 widget to function. Is this the problem? But the tutorial never said I had to add anything to any existing templates.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too.

You have to add `{{ form.media }}` in the head section of your template for django to make it work.

source: http://do-it-big.com/getting-django-easy-select2-to-include-jquery-and-friends/